# Progress bar update in child thread not updating, Work done in main thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, progress-bar

I have an application which has a C# front end (GUI client), and a C++ back end (business logic). The back end is responsible for requesting progress bar functionality and does this by issuing events which the front-end has observer delegates to respond to and act upon. so events are dispatched and responded to in the main thread.

I would like to spawn a second thread to display and update the progress bar, as the main thread is occupied by the back-end doing its thing. While I can show the progress bar window when supposed to, and correctly hide when finished, it will not respond to updates/increments.

`ProgressBarWindow` holds the progress bar control (`pBar`).
`ProgressBarWindow` is owned by `progressBarThread`.

```
public static EventObserver.ProgressBeginEvent pbe = null;
public static EventObserver.ProgressFinishEvent pfe = null;
public static EventObserver.ProgressIncrementEvent pie = null;
public static Thread progressBarThread = null;

static private void InitialiseProgressBarManager()
{

    // Setup the progress bar callbacks...
    pbe = new EventObserver.ProgressBeginEvent(delegate
        (int currentIncrements, int totalIncrements, string message)
    {
        // Create the thread and progress bar window...
        progressBarThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            ProgressBarWindow sw = new ProgressBarWindow();
            sw.pBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
            sw.pBar.Minimum = currentIncrements.Value;
            sw.pBar.Maximum = totalIncrements.Value;
            sw.pBar.Value = 0;
            sw.Show();

            pie = new EventObserver.ProgressIncrementEvent(delegate ()
            {
                sw.pBar.Value++;        // The calling thread cannot access this object... see below 
            });

            pfe = new EventObserver.ProgressFinishEvent(delegate ()
            {
                progressBarThread.Abort();
                progressBarThread = null;
            });
        });

        progressBarThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        progressBarThread.IsBackground = true;
        progressBarThread.Start();
    });
}
```

The window shows when expected, and the `ProgressIncrementEvent` gets raised correctly (it is owned by the thread), however I get an exception when it tries to access the value.

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Do I need a mutex or some other lock? I was hoping the scope of the observer delegate would allow the delegate to have mutable access to the thread local `ProgressBarWindow` even though it is being invoked from the main thread?

I'm not a great C# developer and even less so C# threading so I am a bit stuck about what I should be doing here or even if I can achieve this behaviour. Any help or direction to get this working would be appreciated.

P.S I am using WPF with ProgressBarWindow being defined in XAML.

Comment: The main thread in a GUI app is the UI thread. You should not do hard work on the UI thread. Instead, spawn a worker thread and do hard work there. Let your main (UI) thread only do GUI updates and launch another worker threads.

Comment: @MickyD It is very similar and I did see it, however it didn't mention about the child thread having the GUI control, and I think that might be my problem. Might need a slight redesign as unsure how the frontend can decided if to perform the operation in the background or not. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to access the control using the window´s dispatcher:

```
sw.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => sw.pBar.Value++));
```

Comment: Is there another official `ProgressBar` with an `IsIndeterminate` property?

Comment: @MickyD Sorry for not mentioning it, I am using WPF, and yes `ProgressBarWindow` has the `ProgressBar` member called `pBar`. Have updated.

Comment: @MickyD: No. `pBar` is the `ProgressBar` in the window...

Comment: This answer I think is correct. It's not working for me yet, however I was wondering how to Invoke the control and this answers that bit for me. Thanks. I won't mark it correct until I get it working.

Comment: _"pBar is the ProgressBar in the window"_  - Ohhhhh my bad.  Another gin and tonic for Micky.  +1

Comment: @MickyD agree, the way I feel atm I could do with a fair few of those right now... ;)

Comment: As well as this answer, I had to add a begin invoke action to the thread, `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { ... }));` with my ProgressBarWindow initialisation stuff and then all worked as intended. Thank you.